# azure b2c redirect uri override after registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are using a azure b2c signup custom policy. While user clicks on a register button from [www.domain.com/register](http://www.domain.com/register) SPA to get to azure b2c register page , after successfull registeration we want user to be redirected to a page which is [www.domain.com/editprofile](http://www.domain.com/editprofile)

But currently the AzureB2c Signup policy returns user back to where they come from which is [www.domain.com/register](http://www.domain.com/register). is that possible to change  it ?

Comment: It is indeed very possible to change. However, it depends on your custom policy. I would suggest getting the person who created the policy to change it. Custom policies are fairly verbose, complex and easy to make mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will have to set `UsePolicyInRedirectUri` in `Metadata` of Custom Policy to true.
- Under Custom policies, select `<You_Policy>` and set the `Reply URL` you want.

*Resources:*

- [Define an OAuth2 technical profile in a custom policy - Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/oauth2-technical-profile#metadata)
- [Tutorial - Create user flows and custom policies - Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)